# Compiler stack overflow

Tags: compile

I tried to compile a huge function. I used these options:

```
"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> 
   False}, CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> 
   True}, CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True
```

After 700 seconds it returned this error:

> CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\mypcname-6828\Working-mypcname-6828-4884-1\compiledFunction0.c(1703108) : fatal error C1063: compiler limit : compiler stack overflow >>
>
> Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function. >>

How can I diagnose the problem? I feel this is because of the C compiler limitation.

Comment: Make your "huge function" smaller? Perhaps by breaking in to several sub-functions that can compiled separately.

Comment: Maybe this could help: [C Code Generation User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Overview.html)